# vb.net call to Excel WorksheetFunction causing baffling error "Max method of WorksheetFunction class failed"

Tags: excel, vb.net

In vb (vb.net) calling the `WorksheetFunction.Max()` inside a sub-procedure works, but calling it inside the function below causes the error:

> "Max method of WorksheetFunction class failed".

The function `ANNIE` takes the range `Arg1` and processes the values in each cell later in the code, but it's failing very early on in the code.  It's converted from VBA where it did work (promise!).

Substituting the `Max` for a `Count` function works, but `Max`, `Min`, `Average` doesn't.  Substituting the range inside the `Max()` for pure numbers or writing it in different ways such as ...`range("A:A")` fails. Have tried writing the function `ANNIE` as a sub-procedure but the same problem happens.

So the sub-procedure called `test` will show the `MsgBox` answer without an error.  But calling the function `ANNIE` will cause an error at the `Msgbox` point, even though preceding code is the same.  Suspect it's to do with the `Arg1` as `Excel.Range`, but don't know how or why.
Did randomly try changing `ByVal` to `ByRef` but no change and nor did removing it.

```
Public Sub test()
        Dim oExcelApp As Excel.Application, Training_Data As Excel.Worksheet 
        oExcelApp = CType(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        Dim ActW As Excel.Workbook
        ActW = oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
        Training_Data = ActW.Worksheets("Training_Data")
        MsgBox(oExcelApp.WorksheetFunction.Max(Training_Data.Columns(1).EntireColumn))
    End Sub
```

```
Public Function ANNIE(ByVal Arg1 As Excel.Range)
        Dim oExcelApp As Excel.Application, Training_Data As Excel.Worksheet
        oExcelApp = CType(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        Dim ActW As Excel.Workbook
        ActW = oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
        Training_Data = ActW.Worksheets("Training_Data")
        MsgBox(oExcelApp.WorksheetFunction.Max(Training_Data.Columns(1).EntireColumn))

'....rest of code here

End Function
```

I expect both to show a number as the `MsgBox` result without error.
All and any help really appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes missing references can cause unrelated errors like this

Comment: Good point.  Assume you mean the ref to the DLL/TLB in the Excel sheet?  There's code to check the ref exists and then load it if it doesn't for other parts of the code, but I will now double check the ref is there just before the code stops.

Comment: What is the error that you get? Are you creating an Excel UDF in .NET? If so, how are you doing this? Excel.DNA or something else? The two pieces of code that you show are identical except for the unused `Arg1` argument. So, the problem must be in code that you are not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem had nothing to do with the code in question above and everything to do with minor errors in the code that preceded the call to the ANNIE function itself.  To be specific, an integer variable that was GLOBAL, but accidentally Dimed inside a sub-procedure and caused a NULL transfer value instead of a number was causing the problem.  That integer had nothing to do with the code in question or was used in the code (including subsequent code).  Vb.Net was erroring out in preceding code, but for some reason continuing past the error.  It "crashed" in a different routine many steps downstream from the error.  Thanks to RobertBaron for making me think.  Must just be how the 'assembled' code works and catches errors or not in this case.